# Author Role - Allow editing of Gallery images

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Is it possible to give the 'Author' role the capability of editing image titles and captions on post's they have created ?

I have a number of users set to 'Author' , but when i've tested it's not possible to edit any of the image fields , such as title , caption , description etc.

They can delete images , create WP-Galleries , but cannot edit the details ??

I can do the above with 'Editor' role , but would rather stay with 'Author' for these users.

I've tried a plugin ['user role editor'](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) but cannot get a setting that will allow 'Author' to edit image details , without choosing 'edit others post' , which i dont want.

any help advice appreciated :)

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, to edit those, users have to have capability of 'upload_images'.

User role editor is really a super plugin, just play with some values for Author role and you will definitely find the one that is needed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The author role has 'upload_files' assigned by default; there is no 'upload_images' capability. The question indicates he already tried other capabilities with the User Role Editor plugin and found that 'edit_others_posts' does the trick, but adds too much.